# Android ndk. Can't get reference to JVM

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

A couple of days ago I started having fun with android NDK. Trying to compile one of the sample programs from the book a little problem arised.

So here I need to obtain a reference to JavaVM.

```
// Global env ref (for callbacks)
static JavaVM *g_VM;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jni_Natives_LibMain
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass class, jobjectArray jargv)
{
    // obtain a global ref to the caller jclass
    (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &g_VM); ...
```

Eclipse says "`method 'GetJavaVM()' could not be resolved`" just like about every other line containing methods of `(*env) object`.

Includes directory has path: `C:\programs\IDE\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include` so I don't think it might be something with include paths, however I can be wrong.

Comment: Hm, adding an `#include "jni.h" and just using the exact source compiles ok for me.

Comment: It was working for me but after some time something happened in eclipse i think. I also tried to clear, rebuild and make a new project.

Comment: Just to be clear: it compiles and runs using the NDK compiler, but Eclipse flags the statements as errors?

Answer (score 6):

Are you compiling a .cpp file? <jni.h> has different JNIEnv implementations for C and C++, and you're using the C version. In C++ your code would look like this:

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jni_Natives_LibMain
   (JNIEnv * env, jclass class, jobjectArray jargv)
 {
     // obtain a global ref to the caller jclass
     env->GetJavaVM(&g_VM); ...
```

The normal way to get a JavaVM reference is in JNI_OnLoad:

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* aReserved)
 {
     // cache java VM
     g_VM = vm;
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. It is .c file. The thing is that eclipse is not recognizing (*env)->GetJavaVM() method, it is underlined like an error (only method, not (*env) variable). Also it's not recognizing (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement, (*env)->GetStringUTFChars() etc...

Answer (score -3):

It's the star

`(*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &g_VM);`

is incorrect

`env->GetJavaVM(env, &g_VM);`

is correct and

`(*env).GetJavaVM(env, &g_VM);`

would be correct as well.

Comment: In C, `(*env)->Function(env, arg)` is correct.  In C++, `env->Function(arg)` is correct.  The C and C++ declarations in `jni.h` are different and incompatible.